# Find sum of smaller node from given element in AVL Tree

Tags: java, sorting, tree, logarithm, avl-tree

Can anyone help me.
If i have tree, the inorder traversal AVL Tree is
-1 0 1 2 5 6 9 10 11 12
then i want to have method sumGreater(n)
if

sumGreater(6) = 9 + 10 + 11 + 12 = 42

I tried to modified this.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-greater-nodes-in-avl-tree/
but it wont work.

```
    Node rightRotate(Node y, int key) {
        Node x = y.left;
        Node T2 = x.right;

        x.right = y;
        y.left = T2;

        y.height = max(height(y.left), height(y.right)) + 1;
        x.height = max(height(x.left), height(x.right)) + 1;
        
        int val = (T2 != null) ? T2.desc : -1;
        y.desc = y.desc - (x.desc + key) + (val + key); // modified
        x.desc = x.desc - (val + key) + (y.desc + key); // modified

        return x;
    }
```

```
    int SumGreater(Node root, int x) {
        int res = 0;
     
        while (root != null) {
            int desc = (root.right != null) ? root.right.desc : -1;
            if (root.key > x) {
                res = res + desc + 1 + 1;
                root = root.left;
            } else if (root.key < x) {
                root = root.right;
            } else {
                res = res + desc + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

this still count node not sum of node.
Can anyone help me with O(logN) time complexity
Please help me

corrected code and help

Answer (score 0):

Does `desc` also represent the number of descendant nodes for a node? Then it is unnecessary to take it into account when you want to count the sum of value of nodes greater than n. You should sum their keys. Besides, since your function doesn't modify the tree, there is no need to consider rotation.

Here is my advice code in recursion.

```
    int SumGreater(Node root, int x) {
        int res = 0;
     
        while (root != null) {
            if (root.key > x) {
                res += root.key;
                res += SumGreater(root.right, x);
                root = root.left;
            } else {
                root = root.right;
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I used the attribute to store it so it can run O(log(N)). Honestly, I don't know how much time complexity in this code?

Comment: @GoodDrink My advice code should be O(N) in worst case and O(logN) in best case. If you want to achieve O(logN), I think you need to introduce a variable to record sum of each node's descendant nodes' values like the original ```desc```. After all, ```desc``` is much like a kind of sum which assumes each node's value is 1.